# How can i measure the slope of the tangent in this graphic scale ?

Tags: graph

Hello i am having a difficulty in dealing with this scale , i need to measure the slope of (slope1) by the simple equation y/x .. could you do that one only for me thanks

[image]

Comment: Now Nick Alexeev must appear and say it's off topic.

Comment: Not only is this a absurdly trivial problem, but it has nothing to do with electronics.  Go back to high school, but this time actually pay attention in math class.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Hesitating between offensive and not constructive. Both maybe. No grudge. Just that comments like this *could* and *should* be a little more constructive *and* less harsh.

Comment: @Nash: No, they shouldn't.  This is a dumb question, *and* it doesn't belong here.

Comment: @Olin Granted, does not belong here. However that is *no* reason *not* to say it nicely.

Comment: @Nasha I agree with Olin - short sharp shock treatment gets the message over quickly and, because this is an EE Q&A site I do not wish to debate my opinion and hearing yours is of no consequence.

Comment: dude i am 16 and electronics is a hobby

Comment: Then your high school math class surely covered this only a couple of years ago, right?

Comment: Being 16 would have given you some slack if you had put that information in your profile.  Otherwise, we have no way of knowing.  Remember, your profile isn't for you, it's a courtesy to us.

Comment: i don't like maths very much but i like analogue and digital and embedded systems .. no matter how much i learn maths it always stored in the short memory but i was not sure whether the scale of 0.4 will give me an accurate value of the gain in order to figure out the values of resistors

Comment: i wanted to see whether the users are going to give me an answer with steps of 0.4 or comment on the scale .... this is the only scale that in this topic i didn't learn the logarithmic one

Comment: @carlos sorry to break it to you but engineering is maths. It's the practical implementation/realisation of maths and physics. This question isn't really electronics, its maths... You are after the tangent at a particular point. If you have the equation the. The 1st derivative & solve for the x in question will give you the slope... OR you just read the change in and change in x for any of the red lines. Slope1 has a dy of 1.6 and dx of 6.8. Thus the slope is 1.6/6.8.  NOTE those slopes are not correct anyway

Comment: why not correct ? u mean it should intercept the x axis for the starting voltage only or is there another matter? and please tell me do you think that i may become attracted to maths in future?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum  It took Nick a little while to appear.  He thinks that the question is unclear rather than off-topic.

Comment: @carlos  There is a certain rigor that you need to take on when (a) designing things, (b) asking for help. You have to explain what you are ultimately trying to accomplish.  You have to explain how you have arrived to the question. (I'm not even talking about things like lack of units of measurement on the chart, lack of the schematic, lack of datasheet.) Since you are young and green, you don't understand that there is usually more than one answer, more than one way to "do that one only".  *That* (not the lack of knowledge about slopes and derivatives) is the 16 year old's disadvantage.

Comment: @carlos: Your sloppy writing isn't doing you any favors here.  The first letters of English sentences are capitalized, and so is the word "I".  That and baby talk like "u" for "you" is annoying to read and says you don't care about your problem and respect those you seek help from enough to bother even getting the little things right.  You wouldn't hand in homework this sloppy.  We expect at least the same level of respect you show your teachers.  Right now you're basically thumbing your nose at us, so nobody is going to go out of their way for you.  Presentation and attitude matter, A LOT.

Comment: @OlinLathrop dude take a chill-pill

Comment: @NickAlexeev b0ss can i habe de chichi pls ?

Comment: @carlos  Well, there you go.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of y/x, use dy/dx - as it's a constant slope you get the same ansver.

So pick two convenient X values (e.g where X and Y are easy to read), and let dx be the difference between them.

Now let dy be the difference between the Y values at those same points.

Compute dy/dx and you are done.

Comment: But it's not a constant slope. Right? Slope is varying at each point due to the exponential nature of the graph.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack : Slope is varying. But Slope1 is constant. And the question asks for Slope1.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad.